# Create a folder in Win 7 where files will be deleted after a specified period automatically

Tags: windows-7, file-management, cronjob

I would like to have a folder to put items for temporary use and after a certain amount of time they would be deleted

Is this possible in Windows 7?

I've through of maybe some sort of `.bat` file in startup? But I would prefer doing it without restart.

Can a task be scheduled to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Using a cronjob or a scheduled task (in the Windows world) would solve the problem without being dependent on any starts or logins. Is a single file age for automatic deletion for the whole folder sufficient for you?

Comment: @pabouk Sure,as long as it is created date,that is,the date when I move it in the respective folder.I`m running now wmz solution,and it works only that it takes into account the modified date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) to enumerate and process files not modified longer than (or since date), for example (as shown on linked MS page  - this would simply list them)

`forfiles /s /m *.* /d -365 /c "cmd /c echo @file is at least one year old."`

After you've verified it works as you'd want it to, put it in a batch file and schedule using Task Scheduler (or use `schtasks` if you prefer command line).

[Edit]

If creation date (not modification) date is required, I would resort to powershell: 
This one liner gets and prints all files created earlier that 365 days.
**Please note** it does not strip times from dates (so comparison takes not only date, but also time of creation and time when it runs)!

`powershell -command "gci |? {$_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).addDays(-365)} |% {write $_}"`

To delete instead of list, replace `write` with `del`
To strip time from dates, use `(get-date).date`
You may also want to exclude folders from processing

Comment: How can I delete files based on created date not on modified date?Although most of the times these will be the same.

Comment: @Mihai What you want (and Date&time arithmetic) is rather difficult/problematic in pure batch/cmd. While it is possible [to achieve] I would use powershell for that. See my update.